# signing applications automatically with password in ant

Tags: android, ant, adt

Currently i have a build process in place for all of our apps using `ANT`. I am adding the ability to build a `release` now and sign the apps.

Currently i have the `ant.properties` with the correct properties. And it is in all the projects. And when i build the projects it works fine. Signs, aligns and gives me what i need. HOWEVER, we have many apps and they are all built in the build process.

So the problem is, the user is having to type the password in at the `Please enter keystore password` and the `Please enter password for alias`.

I was wondering if there was a way to get `ant` to enter that password for us or is there another way to sign using `ant` that would work? Maybe i could supply the password when the build process starts and just use that password every time it is asked to be used.

Thanks

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I just have these lines in  my ant.properties and it signs automatically

```
key.store.password=mypasswordOne
key.alias.password=mypasswordTwo
key.store=c:/users/myname/my-release-key.keystore
key.alias=release_alias
```

Comment: This is correct and should solve your problem, you can also use a relative path to the keystore if necessary (e.g. `key.store=somestore.keystore` if it's in the same folder as your project's build.xml).

Comment: One thing that tripped me up: be sure to escape any $'s in your passwords by doubling them ($$). As described here: http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html

Comment: If you put this info into the file does it get included in the apk build so the user can get the passwords?

Comment: Another think to take care is to insert the normal and not inverted slashed: "c:/.../..." instead of "\"

Comment: signing with ant was working fine. but, target api 31 is expecting something more. getting this error : "INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Scanning Failed.: No signature found in package of version 2 or newer" any way to solve with ant ? (OfCourse with "apksigner" sign --ks"  it is solving the issue)

Answer (score 4):

You can use Ant variables in path definition.

```
key.store = ${user.home}/.keystore
```