# Signing Android application using ANT

Tags: java, android, ant

A few similar questions have been asked about this before but I haven't found an answer I can use. Basically I am trying to sign an Android app using ANT.

I have undertaken all the steps necessary (i.e. creating keystore in CLI, editing project.properties file as I cannot find the ant.properites file) and then run "ant release" in CLI and I get the following error which I don't get as I have created a keystore several times now and when the prompt asks me to make my alias password the same as the keystore, i say "yeah why not" and press the enter button.

```
BUILD FAILED
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.6.2/tools/ant/build.xml:1139: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.6.2/tools/ant/build.xml:1151: Signing key speakandroid not found
```

I don't need to edit my build.xml file do I? I think maybe not being able to edit the ant.properties file has something to do with it.

Update: I have made the ant.properties file with the suggestions from @Nick. I also followed these steps to make another keystore in the appName/platforms/android directory:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore speak.keystore
-alias speakAndroid -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

As usual, I get prompted for my name and location details. Then it asks me if I want the  password to be the same as the keystore (I gather this is the alias password/signing key?). I have set it to be a different password.

Within my ant.properties file I have inserted the following:

```
key.store=/Users/Coolwebs/Desktop/phonegap-projects/speakAndroid/platforms/android/speak.keystore
key.alias=speakAndroid
key.store.password=myPassword81
key.alias.password=speakApp
```

Error comes up and still says that it cannot find the signing key for speakandroid alias (scratches head). I know the ant.properties file is doing its job because I have tested it be removing the passwords and seeing what ant in CLI does. The passwords are definitely right. Maybe it's because I have made "dirty" automatic debug versions in the past for beta testing, I really don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just create an ant.properties file in your main project directory. Then edit it to be like my answer to this question:

[signing applications automatically with password in ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932498/signing-applications-automatically-with-password-in-ant)

Comment: Thanks for that. I followed your directions but ant is still refusing to accept my alias password. I set it to be the same as my keystore password. Perhaps I am meant to use a different password. I will attempt to make another keystore and trash this one.

Comment: I tried again and got exactly the same error. I really don't know how this thing works, even after reading the docs. I have edited the code to give more information.

Comment: It worked for one app and not the other. Must be some issues with the build files of the 'bad' app. Will post a comment when I find out what the culprit is.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `-validity` command is not something huge like 100000. I had so many exceptions when trying to build against a keystore with that ;(

Comment: that may have had something to do with it. Will keep this in mind for next time.